# Grouping with different timespans

Tags: date, join, hive, sum, hiveql

currently I am struggling to achieve some aggregation that is kinda overlapping.

The current structure of my table is:

```
|ymd     |id|costs|
|--------|--|-----|
|20200101|a |10   |
|20200102|a |12   |
|20200101|b |13   |
|20200101|c |15   |
|20200102|c |1    |
```

However i'd like to group it in a way that I had different timespan per item. Considering that I am running this query on the 20200103, the result i am trying to achieve is:

```
| timespan   | id | costs |
|------------|----|-------|
| last 2 days| a  |  22   |
| last 1 day | a  |  12   |
| last 2 days| b  |  13   |
| last 1 day | b  |  0    |
| last 2 days| c  |  16   |
| last 1 day | c  |  1    |
```

I have tried many things, but so far I wasn't able to achieve what I need. This is the query that I have tried, with no correct results:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ymd BETWEEN date_add(current_date(),-2) AND to_date(current_date()) THEN '2 days' 
        WHEN ymd BETWEEN date_add(current_date(),-1) AND to_date(current_date()) THEN '1 day'
    END AS timespan,
    id,
    sum(costs) AS costs
FROM `table`
GROUP BY
    CASE 
        WHEN ymd BETWEEN date_add(current_date(),-2) AND to_date(current_date()) THEN '2 days' 
        WHEN ymd BETWEEN date_add(current_date(),-1) AND to_date(current_date()) THEN '1 day'
    END,
    id
```

Comment: date is in a wrong format. ymd between date... will work correctly only if ymd is in yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: I just simplified the sample I posted. I am actually using custom UDFs to convert dates and perform the date_diff on top of the ymd format

Answer (score 0):

You can build a derived table that stores the timestamps, cross join it with the list of distinct users to generate all possible combinations, then bring the table with a `left join` and aggregate:

```
select d.timespan, i.id, coalesce(sum(t.costs), 0) costs
from (select distinct id from mytable) i
cross join (
    select 1 n, 'last 1 day' timespan
    union all select 2, 'last 2 day'
) d 
left join mytable t
    on t.ymd between date_add(current_date(), - d.n) and current_date()
group by d.n, d.timespan, i.id
```